# Filter related values from Django Admin M2M relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to filter related values in Django admin? I have many to many relationship set to be displayed inline.
However there are many values so I want to somehow be able to search/filter those that I need.

So here are the two models (I used Join table):

```
# Create your models here.
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Country')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OpenDestination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Country')
    origin_country = models.ManyToManyField(Country, through='BorderStatus')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class BorderStatus(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('OP', 'OPEN'),
        ('SEMI', 'CAUTION'),
        ('CLOSED', 'CLOSED')
    ]
    Country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    OpenDestination = models.ForeignKey(OpenDestination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='CLOSED')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('Country', 'OpenDestination'))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Country) + ' and ' + str(self.OpenDestination)
```

And in `admin.py`

```
class OpenDestinationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OpenDestination.origin_country.through

class ConutryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        OpenDestinationInline
    ]
    filter_horizontal = ('origin_country',)


admin.site.register(Country, ConutryAdmin)
admin.site.register(OpenDestination)
admin.site.register(BorderStatus)
```

So now when I access one coutry from `Country` model I see list of many countries from `OpenDestination` model (each having own status thanks to the Join Table). Now Im trying to figure out if its possible to filter countries from 'OpenDestination' when accessing single country from 'Country'.

I tried adding filter_vertical/horizontal `filter_vertical = ('name',)` to `CountryAdmin` but Im getting error:

```
The value of 'filter_vertical[0]' must be a many-to-many field.
```

Comment: I think [autocomplete fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) are a better fit to solve this problem.

Comment: Im getting same error when I change filter_vertical to autocomplete_fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your data model didn't make a lot of sense. I rewrote it a bit, to what I think is the intention: destinations (countries) reachable from different sources (also countries).

Data model:

```py
from django.db import models


class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name="Country")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Destination(models.Model):
    destination = models.ForeignKey(
        Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="destinations"
    )
    origin_countries = models.ManyToManyField(
        Country, related_name="origins", through="BorderStatus"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.destination.name


class BorderStatus(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = [("OP", "OPEN"), ("SEMI", "CAUTION"), ("CLOSED", "CLOSED")]
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    origin_country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="CLOSED")

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [("origin_country", "destination")]

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"{self.origin_country.name} -> {self.destination.destination.name}"
            f" ({self.status})"
        )
```

Now the admin that makes more sense to me is the Destination model: this is the one that defines what from which country you can get there. It would look like this:

[image: This is what it would like]

All the country selections here are autocomplete fields.

So we get this admin code:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models


class BorderStatusInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.BorderStatus
    autocomplete_fields = ("origin_country",)


@admin.register(models.Destination)
class OpenDestinationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BorderStatusInline]
    autocomplete_fields = ("destination",)


@admin.register(models.Country)
class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ("name",)
    ordering = ("name",)
```

Comment: Actually I was thinking in opposite way, so I was trying to create model where origin countries have list of destinations that are open to them and actually your solution is just that but the opposite way(Unless Im missing something?). Thanks a lot I will use your suggestion to improve with autocomplete fields now.